# array elements not printing when trying to print in the main function

Tags: c++

I want to find the factors of a product by using arrays to check whether they equal it or not 
the values do not print
here is the code

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int main() {
int arr[5] = { 1,3,5,7,2 };
int arr1[5] = { 0,6,5,4,9 };
int X;



cout << "Please enter X:"; cin >> X;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5 && j < 5; ++i, ++j) {
    if (arr[i]*arr[j]==X) {

        cout << arr[i] << " "; 
        cout << arr1[j] << " ";

    }


}


   }
```

Comment: You still have `i == j`, so you check only those 5 values: `1*0, 3*6, 5*5, 7*4, 2*9`. (0, 18, 25, 28, 18).

Comment: 2 loops, one for i, one for j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this nested loops

```
      for (int i = 0; i < 5 ;++i) {
           for(int j=0 ;j<5;++j){
            if (arr[i]*arr1[j]==X) {
                cout << arr[i] << " "; 
                cout << arr1[j] << " ";
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: or even `for (int i : arr) {for(int j : arr1) { if (i * j == X){/*..*/}}}`